How to use Axios with Laravel 10 and Vite?
I want to make an Ajax call using Axios in Laravel 10 with Vite (I don't use VueJs).
I get the error "axios is not defined".
My view :
<x-app-layout>
   

    <div class="py-12">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto sm:px-6 lg:px-8 space-y-6">
            <div class="p-4 sm:p-8 bg-white dark:bg-gray-800 shadow sm:rounded-lg">
                hello world
            </div>
            
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
            axios.get("{{route('scann','xxx')}}"
            ).then(function(rep){
                console.log(rep)
            })
        
    </script>
</x-app-layout>

in the layout I have included css and js before closing header with :
@vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'])
app.js :
import './bootstrap';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';

window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();


bootstrap.js :
/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';


It's likely that app.js isn't loaded until after the script tag in your view (Vite scripts are type="module" by default, so loading is deferred). Try waiting until the DOM is loaded:
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
        axios.get('/some-endpoint')
            .then(response => console.log(response))
            .catch(error => console.error(error));
    });
</script>


Defining global variables and inlining scripts are not good practices, but Blade and alpine.js both seem to encourage doing that.
If your app isn't too big, maybe you can put everything in app.js (in, imported from, indirectly imported from, whatever as long as it's in the build system's output app.js file).

How does this even address the actual issue?

how to call a function defined in app.js in a blade template then ?

The moment you use Blade you lose almost all IDE support except syntax highlighting and formatting, but that's up to you in the end. Keeping as much JS as you can inside the JS build system is safer but does bring its own challenges. There are ways for JS to identify the current page, pull data from the DOM or from the server and execute page-specific logic so there's no need to put it in the template if Blade puts the data in the DOM.
